# const within block scopes in Node and Chrome (V8)

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, constants, v8

I am writing a nodejs (v4.2.4) app were I encountered some odd behaviour.

```
function A(number) {
 this.number = number;
}

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const a = new A(i);

  console.log(a.number);
}

const b = new A(99);
console.log(b.number);
```

My intuition, coming from Java (and the one of FireFox), is that the output should have been

```
0
1
2
99
```

However, Node (and Chrome) give me

```
0
0
0
99
```

I investigated and understood from [MSN - block scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) that `var` does not have block scope in javascript. Looking further, [MSN - const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) describes a const declaration as having block scope though:

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. The value of a constant cannot change through re-assignment, and it can't be redeclared.

In that case I would say that Node and Chrome (in that case probably V8), have some kind of shady handling of `const` in block scopes. But they also write that

> This declaration creates a constant that can be either global or local to the function in which it is declared.

Does that mean that V8 puts every `const` declaration as a global variable while FireFox creates a local one? How can it be that something crucial like that is implemented so differently?

Comment: I would think Node and Chrome are doing it right because you are setting i using var

Comment: Actually, according to the spec, only firefox is doing it right

Comment: This is a known, well documented [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2198)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

v8 requires `use strict` directive to enable this behaviour. This has changed in latest version: http://v8project.blogspot.ru/2016/01/v8-release-49.html

Quote:

> Release 4.9 also makes block level constructs such as class and let available outside of strict mode

This should also apply to `const`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the actual bug here, V8 has required strict mode to use `let` for some time, and fixing that in version 4.9 does not fix the block scope issue with `const`

Comment: @adeneo, no, the answer is correct. Before 4.9, V8 still provided the old (`var`-like) web legacy behaviour for `const` in sloppy mode. Now ES6 semantics applies there as well.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg - Indeed, I misread the release note as just fixing the old *"...not yet supported outside strict mode"* that you get with `let`, and as `const` doesn't throw that error, I assumed the bug with block scope was still there outside strict mode. Thank you for finally fixing that annoying bit, now if only we could have subclassing and proxies as well...

Comment: @adeneo, 4.9 has proxies and subclassing.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg - I noticed, and destructuring assignments as well, great stuff

Answer (score -4):

Chrome does not support ES6 by default. That const behavior you are citing is from ES6 specification.

That strange `const` behavior in Chrome is non standard, neither in ES5 (that has no such feature at all) nor in ES6.

It is failing basic tests: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

`const` must have local, block scope.

Comment: It's actually just behaviour to Chrome 48, the others seem to be fine

Comment: @Quill Yes, I've provided link that outlines that.