# const in Node, in different blocks

Tags: javascript, node.js, constants

On occasion I see Node barf when it sees code like this:

```
if (true) {
    const z = 'foo';
} else {
    const z = 'bar';
}
```

Node says that z has already been declared as constant. But since this is an if-else, at what point does Node actually see both declarations? Does the eval operation in Node catch this somehow?

Comment: Are you in strict mode? If not, the `const` is probably hoisted outside of the block.

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: @Bergi I just tested in node v6.2.0 in non-strict mode. This does not throw an error.

Comment: Yeah no error on 6.2.0, but I am almost 100% certain the error does come up in a 4.x or 5.x version, and I wonder why

Comment: Older versions had some bugs with `let` and `const` and would, in certain cases/versions, treat them as `var`.

Comment: not an exact duplicate, but read [const within block scopes in Node and Chrome (V8)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35234850/1048572) about some of the quirks with `const` in older versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node 4 and 5 have incomplete support for `const`. One of the missing features is support for block scope outside of strict mode.

[More info at this support table.](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-const)

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Node v6, they implemented an earlier draft of the specification, in which `const` variables were block scoped. Declaring two const variables in the same scope with the same name resulted in an error, however declaring a const variable in a loop behaved strangely: the constant got the value from the first assignment. Any further assignment had no effect.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const j = i;
    console.log(j)l // prints 0 all three times in node 5.x
}
```